# How do I output a string of characters based on some rules and an initial string of characters?

Tags: python

Basically, I want to know how to replace every A, + and - in a string of A's,+'s and -'s based on rules inputted.
So if I have a chain of the characters mentioned above, and I input that every A will become A+A, every - will become -+-, every + will become A-+. How do I "choose" every single one of the characters in the initial chain, and change them to the replacements so that it outputs the "new" chain?

Being a beginner to Python, I tried basic commands like

```
input:"Initial chain: "

input:"What does A become? "

input:"What does + become? "

input:"What does - become? "
```

but I do not know what to go from there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

**You could just make a blank output string variable and then loop through the characters of the initial chain**

If the character at any given position is 'A', then concatenate the output string with 'A+A'.

Else if it is '-' concatenate '-+-'.

Else if it is '+' concatenate 'A-+'.

Else just add the original character to the output string.

```java
chain = input('Initial chain: ')
r1 = input('What does A become? ')
r2 = input('What does + become? ')
r3 = input('What does - become? ')

i = 2 # amount of iterations you would like
while i > 0:
  result = ''
  for c in chain:
    if c == 'A':
      result += r1
    elif c == '+':
      result += r2
    elif c == '-':
      result += r3
    else:
      result += c
  i -= 1
  chain = result

print(chain)
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```html
original = input("Initial Chain: ")
in1 = input("What does A become? ")
in2 = input("What does + become? ")
in3 = input("What does - become? ")

print(original.replace("A",in1).replace("+",in2).replace("-",in3))
```

Comment: Wait, that does not work, I just tried running it and the result is different to what I did by hand. All -'s dissapeared.

Comment: Do you know any wait to fix this?